# Verilog error: expecting a colon, and expecting a equal sign

Tags: verilog

I am currently working on an assignment about ALU using Quartus 16.0. As a beginner of Verilog, I really had a bad time due to lacking of relevant knowledge.
Tried hard to find the problem in the code but still need help.

```
reg [7:0] ALUout;
    always@(*)
    begin
    case(keys[2:0])
    3'b000: add plus(.a0(a0), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .b0(b0), .b1(b1), .b2(b2), .b3(b3), .s0(ALUout[0]), .s1(ALUout[1]), .s2(ALUout[2]), .s3(ALUout[3]), .cout(ALUout[4]));
    3'b001: ALUout = A + B;
    3'b010: ALUout = {A | B, A ^ B};
    3'b011: function3 u0(.a0(a0), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .b0(b0), .b1(b1), .b2(b2), .b3(b3), .Out(ALUout)); 
    3'b100: function4 u1(.a0(a0), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .b0(b0), .b1(b1), .b2(b2), .b3(b3), .Out(ALUout));
    endcase
end
```

Here's the error message:

Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Lab3Part3.v(274) near text: "plus";  expecting "<=", or "=".

Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at Lab3Part3.v(274) near text: ";";  expecting ":", or ",".

and same for the other lines.

So far I've only learned a tiny bit of always block and barely case statement in class, please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate a module inside a procedural block. Move the module instantiation outside the always block and connect the module's output to a wire of proper width. In the always block, reference the wire.

Also, `ALUout` needs to have a known assignment in all possible combinations within the always block. Otherwise a complex latch could be inferred. A `default` should be used to handle the conditions of `keys[2:0]` having the values 5, 6, or 7.

```
reg [7:0] ALUout;
wire [4:0] add_out;
wire [7:0] func3_out, func4_out;
add plus(.a0(a0), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .b0(b0), .b1(b1), .b2(b2), .b3(b3), .s0(add_out[0]), .s1(add_out[1]), .s2(add_out[2]), .s3(add_out[3]), .cout(add_out[4]));
function3 u0(.a0(a0), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .b0(b0), .b1(b1), .b2(b2), .b3(b3), .Out(func3_out));
function4 u1(.a0(a0), .a1(a1), .a2(a2), .a3(a3), .b0(b0), .b1(b1), .b2(b2), .b3(b3), .Out(func4_out));
always@(*)
    begin
    case(keys[2:0])
    3'b000: ALUout = {3'b0,add_out}; // leading zero padding
    3'b001: ALUout = A + B;
    3'b010: ALUout = {A | B, A ^ B};
    3'b011: ALUout = func3_out;
    3'b100: ALUout = func4_out;
    default: ALUout = 8'b0; // without this like ALUout would be an inferred latch
    endcase
end
```